# Function returns Ajax response - Value is undefined? jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

When I alert the returned value from the jsonServerResponse function, its value is undefined - despite JSON being returned from the process.php page.

```
function jsonServerResponse(operation, JSOoptionalData) {
        JSOoptionalData = (typeof JSOoptionalData == "undefined") ? 'defaultValue' : JSOoptionalData
        var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: "apicommand=" + JSOoptionalData,
            success: function (json) {
                return jQuery.parseJSON(json);
            }
        });
}

alert("Response as JS Object: "+jsonServerResponse("operation"));
```

I know that the problem is that the alert function made before the asynchronous request is complete, but I am unsure how to fix this problem. Any advice is really appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out from a different post. The result can either be handled within the success callback, or you can add an argument that is itself a callback function and apply the result of the ajax request to the callback.

```
function jsonServerResponse(operation, callback, JSOoptionalData) {
        JSOoptionalData = (typeof JSOoptionalData == "undefined") ? 'defaultValue' : JSOoptionalData
        jqxhr = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "process.php",
            data: "apicommand=" + operation + "&optionaldata" + JSON.stringify(JSOoptionalData),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (json) {
                if(typeof callback === 'function') callback.apply(this, [json]);
            }
        });
}


jsonServerResponse("get_something_from_server", function(returnedJSO){
     console.log(returnedJSO.Result.Some_data);
}, "optional_data");
```

And gdoron, the line you have asked about makes the third argument optional. I hear it's good practice, if you are going to pass some data onto the server (but you dont know how many variables) to add an optional argument and just pass a js object, convert this to a JSON string, and decode it server-side.

Peace! :)

Answer (score 5):

This is because the AJAX request is asynchronous, so the `return` is hit before the call completes, so the function always returns null.

You need to call the code which relies on the AJAX call, from within the `success` call back itself. Try this:

```
function jsonServerResponse(operation, JSOoptionalData) {
    JSOoptionalData = (typeof JSOoptionalData == "undefined") ? 'defaultValue' : JSOoptionalData
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: "apicommand=" + JSOoptionalData,
        success: function (json) {
            alert("Response as JS Object: " + json);

            // to see more information about the object returned, use console.log:
            console.log(json);
        }
    });
}

jsonServerResponse("operation")
```

Comment: Is there any way to capture the data from the request into a variable outside of the success call back?

Comment: @TaylorMac You can still put it into a global variable, but you have to be very careful to only use the variable once the AJAX call has completed. The best method is to call a function from your `success` handler, passing the result of the AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

You nailed the problem, ajax is an async operation, you can use the returned data only in the success callback:

```
function jsonServerResponse(operation, JSOoptionalData) {
    // What that line suppose to do???
        JSOoptionalData = (typeof JSOoptionalData == "undefined") ? 'defaultValue' : JSOoptionalData
        var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: "apicommand=" + JSOoptionalData,
            dataType: "json", // Change the dataType to json.
            success: function (json) {
                console.log("Response as JS Object:") 
                console.log(json);
            }
        });
}
```