# Function return async response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Like a person asked here (but his solutions as to call a nother function) https://stackoverflow.com/a/10796326/315200 ...I would like to know if its possible to have a function which doesn't call a second function on response of an async request, but simply `return` when the async request responses.

**Something like this maybe:**

```
function callToFacebook() {
    var fbResponse;

    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
        fbResponse = response;
    });

    return fbResponse; //Will return undefined because CallToFacebook is async
}
```

Isn't that possible some way, without calling another function??

What I'm trying to achieve is to have one function I can call with some parameters, which will return the response `object` from a async webservice, like FB.

Comment: If it was possible, this would have been given as answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no. You cannot have an asynchronous function return a meaningful value synchronously, because that value does not exist at that time (as it is built asynchronously in the background).

You can, however, return a [Promise](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object, representing the "potential return value" of the asynchronous operation, and bind a function to that object using [done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) or similar. That way, your function gets return semantics (instead of having to chain the control flow into a callback), and remains asynchronous.

Comment: can you give one example of this in jsfiddle plz

Answer (score 2):

**No**, it's not possible.

You can't return value that is returned from async operation.

Think about it, you tell 10 people to have one mile running contest, they start now, will finish in one minute +-, but you want to know the answer **now**, it's not possible unless you're cheating...

Comment: I just want the function to wait with the response, not guess nor cheat.

Comment: @KennethB. SO the answer is it's not possible,